# Помогите исправить ошибку в коде С

Tags: c

```
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF612D25A22 в lab3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000007757300008.
```

Ошибка при выполнении кода, которую я не понимаю так как чайник в данном деле пока.

```
void main(void) {

    int r=1, r2=0, s, s2 = 0, arrey[5][5];
    for (r = 1; r <= 5; r++) {
        for (s = 1; s <= 5; s++) {

            printf("Vvedit znachennya A%d,%d = ", r, s); scanf_s("%d", &arrey[r2][s2]);
            s2 = s2 + 1;
        };
        s2 = 1;
        s = 1;
        r2 = r2 + 1;
        printf(".\n");

        
    };
    
    int i=0, k=0, f, x, j, y;

    j = 0; f = 0;
    r2 = 0; s2 = 0;

    while (i < 25) {
        k = arrey[r2][s2];

        for (r2 = 0; r2 < 5; r2++) {
            if (r2 == 0) {
                for (s2 = 0; s2 < 5; s2++) {
                    if (arrey[r2][s2] < k) arrey[r2][s2] = k; x = r2; y = s2;

                };
            }
            else if (r2 == 1) {
                for (s2 = 0; s2 < 5; s2++) {
                    if (arrey[r2][s2] < k) arrey[r2][s2] = k; x = r2; y = s2;

                };
            }
            else if (r2 == 2) {
                for (s2 = 0; s2 < 5; s2++) {
                    if (arrey[r2][s2] < k) arrey[r2][s2] = k; x = r2; y = s2;

                };
            }
            else if (r2 == 3) {
                for (s2 = 0; s2 < 5; s2++) {
                    if (arrey[r2][s2] < k) arrey[r2][s2] = k;  x = r2; y = s2;

                };
            }
            else if (r2 == 4) {
                for (s2 = 0; s2 < 5; s2++) {
                    if (arrey[r2][s2] < k) arrey[r2][s2] = k; x = r2; y = s2;

                };
            };

        };

        arrey[x][y] = arrey[j][f];
        arrey[j][f] = k;
        if (f < 5) { f++; }
        else { f = 0; j++; r2 = j; f = s2; };

    };

    for (r2 = 0; r2 < 5; r2++) {
        printf("(");
        for (s2 = 0; s2 < 5; s2++) {
            printf("\'%d\'", arrey[r2][s2]);

        };
        printf(")\n");
    };


    system("pause");
};
```

Как я понял что-то, связано с массивом. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Весь алфавит в именах переменных. Как вы сами-то это читаете?

Comment: Вы выходите за границы массива здесь `scanf_s("%d", &arrey[r2][s2]);`, и начинайте с нуля в циклах `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s2 = 1;
```

Тут, по видимому, нужен был 0, иначе происходит попытка записи в `arrey[r2][5]`

---

```
while (i < 25) {
```

А где, собственно, меняется эта `i`?

---

```
arrey[x][y] = arrey[j][f];
arrey[j][f] = k;
```

Тут переменные индексов бывают >=5; выход за пределы массива.
Необходимо пересмотреть код, меняющий эти индексы.

---

```
if (f < 5) { f++; } // if (f+1 < 5) f++;
```

Проверяется валидность текущего значения, а не после инкремента.
В итоге `f = 5` просачивается в индексы массива.

---

```
if (r2 == 0) {
```

Ввиду одинаковости тела всех этих if можно объединить под `if (r2 < 5)`.
Так как это же условие проверяется в самом цикле, условие можно удалить.

---

```
if (arrey[r2][s2] < k) arrey[r2][s2] = k; x = r2; y = s2;
```

Обратите внимание на то, что условие относится только к первому оператору.
Добавьте фигурные скобки.

---

Как я бы описал подобный код(с учётом того, что я не стал разбираться в смысле «полезной» работы):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int *arr, size_t N, size_t M) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("Vvedit znachennya A%d,%d = ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i*M+j]);
        };
        printf("\n");
    };
}

void doSomething(int *arr, size_t N, size_t M) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            arr[i*M + j] = (i+j) * arr[i*M + j];
        };
    };
}

void print(int *arr, size_t N, size_t M) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("\'%d\'", arr[i*M+j]);
            if (j < M - 1) {
                printf(", ");
            }
        };
        printf("]\n");
    };
}

int main() {
    size_t M, N;
    scanf("%lu %lu", &M, &N);
    int array[N][M];

    input((int*)(array), N, M);
    print((int*)array, N, M);

    printf("Do something\n");
    doSomething((int*)array, N, M);
    print((int*)array, N, M);
};

// gcc -Wall 1204765.c -o 1204765 && ./1204765 <<< '3 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3'
```

Comment: Задание кода поставлено на сортировке введенной матрицы по возрастанию методом выбора. Ошибку я устранил, проблема была в `while(i<25) ` добавил ` i++ `  но сортировка не работает.

Comment: Вставил в вопросе отредактированный код

Comment: Не понимаю как мне сделать чтобы при проверке минимального значения массива, предыдущий минимальный элемент уже не проверялся. Так как когда я нашел минимальное значение, я меняю его местами с 1 элементом, второе минимальное значение, но которое больше первого минимального, со вторым элементом и так далее.

Comment: Обновлённый вопрос настолько отличается от оригинала, что мой ответ теперь не имеет смысла. Не надо так. [Задайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) новый вопрос, а этот откатите.

Comment: Извените, не подумал, откатил